# How to pass an image to layer in react-mapbox-gl and prevent refresh for center reset?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps

I've been working with react-map-gl to map a lot of points on a map. It worked but was laggy since I was re-rendering points every time the map shifted. I've been switching over to react-mapbox-gl which I have read is much faster when implementing features on a layer. ***I'd like to add an image like this one to each feature, but I am unsure how to***

https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/computer.png

It seems that images in this library are passed to `Layer` as an argument, but I cant find any good documentation on this other than this blurb in the documentation:

https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md
*images: [imageKey: string, image: HTMLImageElement, options: object] Also accepts array of the previous image tuple. Add images for use in layout with prop icon-image. The value should be the imageKey string of the tuple. Alternatively, use mapbox studio to upload the image, it will be fetched with the map style object. (see map.addImage options for the tuple options).*

***Lastly I am noticing when I do user geolocation and set state on the center or even render a popup it takes a while to re-render, am I doing something off here?***

Can someone point me in the right direction on these two? I may be implementing procedures incorrectly. My code is below:

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import ReactMapGL, { Marker, Popup}  from 'react-map-gl';
import ReactMapboxGl, { Marker, Layer, Feature, ZoomControl, Popup, luster } from 'react-mapbox-gl';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewport: {
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        latitude: 40.7128,
        longitude: -74.0060,
        zoom: 10
      },
      zoom: [10], //for alex mapbox-gl
      center: [-74.0060, 40.7128], //for alex mapbox-gl
      link: undefined,
      links: [],
      selectedLink:null,
      userLocation:[],
      searchInput: "",
      showMatches: false,
      matches: [],
      searchLink: [],
      showInfo: false
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/s4kf-3yrf.json')
      .then(res=> res.json())
      .then(res=> 
          //console.log(json)
          this.setState({links:res})
      );
  }


  markerClick = (feature) => {
    //feature.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      center: [parseFloat(feature.longitude), parseFloat(feature.latitude)],
      zoom: [14]
    });
    this.setState({selectedLink:feature});
    //this.renderPopup(feature);
  };

  render() {

    const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
          accessToken:
            'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmF1c2x5Zm94MTEwIiwiYSI6ImNrMXBlOTdsejB3NzIzbW1pdnV0bHVsYWMifQ.ugYTVKKKHoUw0Ij-IjV37Q'
        });

    //parseFloat(link.longitude), parseFloat(link.location)
    const markers = this.state.links.map((link, index) => (
      <Feature
        key={link.cb_link_id}
        onClick={this.markerClick.bind(this,link)}
        coordinates={[parseFloat(link.longitude), parseFloat(link.latitude)]}
        properties={{linkName: link.cb_link_id}}>
      </Feature>
      ))

      const setUserLocation = () => {
        console.log("attempting to get user location ...")
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          let setUserLocation = 
              [position.coords.longitude,
                position.coords.latitude];
           this.setState({
             zoom: [14],
             center: setUserLocation,
             userLocation: setUserLocation
          });
       });
      }



    return (
      <div>
      <div><button onClick={setUserLocation}>My Location</button></div>
      <Map
        zoom ={this.state.zoom}
        center={this.state.center}
        style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        containerStyle={{
        height: '100vh',
        width: '100vw'
      }}
      >
         <ZoomControl
            zoomDiff={1}
            onControlClick={this._onControlClick}/>

          <Layer
            type="circle"
            id="marker"
            image={<img width={20} height={20}  src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/100/000000/worldwide-location.png" alt = "user_location"/>}
            paint={{'circle-color':"#ff5200"}}>
            {markers}
          </Layer>
          {Object.keys(this.state.userLocation).length !== 0 ? (
              <Marker
                coordinates={this.state.userLocation}
              >
               <img width={20} height={20}  src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/100/000000/worldwide-location.png" alt = "user_location"/>
              </Marker>
              ) : ( 
              <div>Empty</div>
            )}
          {this.state.selectedLink ? (
            <Popup
              coordinates={[parseFloat(this.state.selectedLink.longitude), parseFloat(this.state.selectedLink.latitude)]}
              offset={{
              'bottom-left': [12, -38],  'bottom': [0, -38], 'bottom-right': [-12, -38]
               }}>
                <div>
              <h2>{this.state.selectedLink.community_board}</h2>
              <p>{this.state.selectedLink.council_district}</p>
              <p>{this.state.selectedLink.latitude}</p>
              <p>{this.state.selectedLink.longitude}</p>
            </div>
            </Popup>
          ) : null}
      </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```